# Javascript + Google Map: how to get geolocation and then assign center of the map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is probably a very basic question. I have the code working but it is logically wrong.

I need to find the geolocation and set the center of map there. If I can't access the geolocation, then I want to set the center at New Heaven. I know that I should use callbacks but I don't know how.

Right now the code works, but it is slow. It first sets the center to New Heaven and then jumps to the real geolocation. I want to it go to the real one straight away. How should I achieve that?

Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

let canvas = $("#map-canvas").get(0);

// Styles for map
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
let styles = [
    // Hide Google's labels
    {
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            {visibility: "off"}
        ]
    },
    // Hide roads
    {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
            {visibility: "off"}
        ]
    }
];
// Options for map
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
let options = {
    center: {lat: 41.3184, lng: -72.9318},//new heaven
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    maxZoom: 14,
    panControl: true,
    styles: styles,
    zoom: 13,
    zoomControl: true
};

// Instantiate map
map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);

//reset center if geolocation is accessible (HERE IS THE PROBLEM)
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        map.setCenter(pos);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map:map,
        label:"Around Me"
        });
    });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it to center at "New Heaven", then don't set the center until the geolocation callback returns a value.  The disadvantage of that, is that if the geolocation fails (the user denies it, or the browser doesn't support it), the map won't display at all.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x7eh4mj1/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let canvas = $("#map-canvas").get(0);

  // Styles for map
  // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
  let styles = [
    // Hide Google's labels
    {
      featureType: "all",
      elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
      }]
    },
    // Hide roads
    {
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
      }]
    }
  ];
  // Options for map
  // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
  let options = {
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    maxZoom: 14,
    panControl: true,
    styles: styles,
    zoom: 13,
    zoomControl: true
  };

  // Instantiate map
  map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);

  //reset center if geolocation is accessible (HERE IS THE PROBLEM)
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      map.setCenter(pos);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map,
        label: "Around Me"
      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```